# Showing a custom marker on user his position

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-overlay

I am using `Google Maps v2 Android MapView`. The marker of the position of the user is a *blue circle*. I want to change this to my `drawable`.

Is this possible?

I know I can add markers like this but this doesn't apply to the user his own position:

```
this.marker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker);
this.map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position).title(name)
                .draggable(false).icon(this.marker));
```

Comment: How did you fix it? i want the same disable blue marker but enable the location button

Comment: We continued the answer on the this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25540/discussion-between-karan-rana-and-klaasvaak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can add your custom marker to show user current location....but you need to calculate the latitude and longitude your self using locationListener and show that location on map as follows:

```
public void setCurretnLocMarker(loc) {

        LatLng mLatLng=new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
        getMap().animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mLatLng));

        getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mLatLng).title(mLatLng.toString()).draggable(false));
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't this add the custom marker onto the blue circle? So I would still see the blue circle.

Comment: See the blue circle is visible only if you add the following iin your code:

 myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

and if you dont want to show the blue circle then remove this line

Comment: I want to have the button that shows the user his location. But I want a custom marker. But doing myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false) this button is gone.

Comment: When I set it to false the button is gone.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25540/discussion-between-karan-rana-and-klaasvaak)

Answer (score 0):

The way that comes to  my mind is that.

1) You have the latlng of the current position ... add marker with custom drawable on it.
2) Disible current location on googlemap..
 TO disable it think the call is

```
mGoogleMapObject.setLocationEnable(false);
```

Thats it.

Comment: I want to have the button that shows the user his location. But I want a custom marker. But doing myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false) this button is gone.